# PHP custom session handler not working?

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo, session-variables

I am in the process of building a database-driven website which needs to include user authentication. If I use standard file-based session management, all works as expected but if I try to use a custom session handler (so that sessions are saved in the database), the only things that seem to get stored are the ID and the timestamp.

Anything saved in a `$_SESSION` variable is nuked (although interestingly this only occurs if I use `header(Location: ...)` to redirect to another page upon successful login.

This is my session handler class file:

```
// include class files
require_once('database.php');
require_once('database-functions.php');

// set up session handler class
class Session {

    private $session_login  = null;
    private $session_db         = null;

    public function __construct() {

        // connect to database
        $this -> session_login  = new Database;
        $this -> session_db         = new SimplifiedDB;

        $session_db_info = $this -> session_login -> getLogin();

        $this -> session_db -> dbConnect(
            $session_db_info['host'],
            $session_db_info['user'],
            $session_db_info['pass'],
            $session_db_info['database']);

    }

    // open
    public function open($save_path, $session_name) {

        return true;

    }

    // close
    public function close() {

        return true;

    }

    // read
    public function read($id) {

        $get_data = $this -> session_db -> dbGetVariable('session', 'data', array('id' => $id));

        if(empty($get_data)) {

            return '';

        } else {

            return $get_data['data'];

        }

    }

    // write
    public function write($id, $data) {

        $access = time();

        $get_data = $this -> session_db -> dbGetVariable('session', 'id', array('id' => $id));

        if(empty($get_data)) {

            // no ID, insert a record
            $write_query = $this -> session_db -> dbInsert('session', array(
                'id'        => $id,
                'data'      => $data,
                'access'    => $access));

            return true;

        } else {

            // ID exists, update it
            $write_query = $this -> session_db -> dbUpdate('session', array(
                'id'        => $id,
                'data'      => $data,
                'access'    => $access));

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

    // destroy (destroys a session)
    public function destroy($sessionId) {

        $destroy_query = $this -> session_db -> dbDelete('session', array('id'  => $sessionId));

        return true;

    }


    // garbage collector (randomly deletes old sessions)
    public function gc($lifetime) {

        $the_time = time();

        $sql = "DELETE FROM 'session' WHERE 'access' + $lifetime < $this_time";
        $gc_query = $this -> session_db -> dbExecuteQuery($sql);

        return true;

    }

}
```

I am using a [SimplifiedDB](http://codecanyon.net/item/simplified-db-pdo-mysqli-mysql-helper-class/3928442) class (`database-functions.php`) to connect to the MySQL database using PDO, and the `database.php` file is another class which contains my database credentials.

I've spent many hours on this problem and for the life of me cannot figure out where I am going wrong. I have a `header.php` file which I include as the first line of every PHP file, contents are as follows:

```
require_once('sessions.php');

$user_session = new Session();

session_set_save_handler(
    array($user_session, 'open'),
    array($user_session, 'close'),
    array($user_session, 'read'),
    array($user_session, 'write'),
    array($user_session, 'destroy'),
    array($user_session, 'gc'));

register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');

session_start();
```

I did originally have that stuff in the Session constructor in my session handler class, but I put it in a separate class in the end (probably out of desperation). My web host says that there are no server issues with regards to session management, and I also have this problem on my localhost webserver so it's definitely something wrong in the code.

I should also point out that I've done some other checks such as making sure my `header.php` file is located on the first line of each PHP file, and I use `exit()` after all redirects, as follows:

```
$_SESSION['test'] = 'testval';
header("Location: /index.php");
exit();
```

(using a full URL in the header line above makes no difference by the way, I still have disappearing session variables).

Thanks for taking the time to read this, hopefully someone might be able to point anything out that I have missed? :)

Comment: Please remove all non-essential code and try with a barebones example that increments a session counter variable on page refresh. If that works, your bug is not in the session code. As an aside, reading from the db and writing to it on every session access is extremely wasteful. Keep the data in memory and read/write it inside `open` and `close`.

Comment: I have tried using the class files above with a test PHP file which literally has the three lines of code above but it still doesn't save the session variable when the page is redirected. If I don't redirect, it keeps the session variable and saves it to the DB. Will try your counter incrementing suggestion though, thanks.

Comment: Just tried using a session counter, it worked the first time (saving to the DB), the second time it just wiped the data field in the DB for that session record.